# AchartEngine - Remove unwanted dates

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I have added the following 4 dates in my Chart View, in TimeSeries.

```
2-Jan-2013
3-Jan-2013
4-Jan-2013
7-Jan-2013
```

When I see the result in the emulator, the graph shows 5th and 6th Jan also. How do I remove the dates which I have not included?

I am preparing a chart to show traffic during working days. So, I want to add the next Monday immediately after this Friday. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the behavior by calling:

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the solution. The unwanted dates are gone, but the gap is still there between 4th Jan and 7th Jan. Can you please tell me how to remove the gap??